# Combinatorics: Building 10 groups of 100 elements while elements remain sorted

Tags: php, combinatorics, combinations

I've got a problem concerning combinatorics. Unfortunately, I can't describe it abstractly so I try to explain it as a story. :)

**Problem:**

1. There are 100 children on the schoolyard.
2. They all have unique heights, assuming the values are 100-199cm.
3. You want to build 10 groups, each consisting of 1-99 children.
4. How can you build all the groups while the children must be sorted by their height?
5. I need all possible solutions for these groups since it isn't hard to find one constellation.

**Short and easy:**

All 100 children stand side by side. You only have to decide where to split them into groups and find all solutions for this.

**Example (values are the heights):**

[120 ... 190 ... 199] ... [126 ... 137 ... 144 ... 188] *is not possible*

[101] ... [104 ... 105 ... 112 ... 149] ... [169 ... 189] *is possible*

I hope you can help me. Thank you very much in advance!

PS: It's no homework. ;) Normally, I need a function which does this with numbers. But I couldn't describe this abstractly like "building k groups of numbers while all numbers are sorted". I thought you wouldn't understand it this way. :) A solution in PHP would be best but I would be glad to see solutions in other languages as well. :)

Comment: In the end, you don't have to put all the 100 children in the groups?

Comment: Just to check I understand - is your first example not possible because 190 (in the 1st group) is bigger than 126 (in the 2nd group)?

Comment: @Bruno Reis: Yes, you have to put every children into one gorup. You're right, the example is a bit confusing. I've corrected it with "..."

Comment: @marco92w: in the 2nd example, where is child 106? to the left of [104, 105, 112, 149]? or to the right of it? I can't understand why this is possible and the first is not possible.

Comment: Another question: do you have to build exatcly 10 groups? Or at most 10 groups? Your problem is not very well explained...

Comment: @Bruno Reis: The first one is not possible because the 199 must never be to the left of 126 since it's bigger. ;)

Comment: @marco92w: so, your statement implies that 199 MUST be the last one, and if so, 198 must be the just before 198, and so on... is this your problem? If so, I insist: in example 2, where is 106?

Comment: @Bruno Reis: The 106 can also be between the 105 and the 112. In the groups (brackets) there are some numbers missing as well. I hope the new notation shows this better!? You must build exactly 10 groups since a group must contain one element or more.

Comment: @marco92w: so, your problem is this your problem? "write the numbers 100 to 199, sorted, then make disjoint 10 circles, each one containing at least one number, and the 10 circles must contain all the 100 numbers" ?

Comment: @Bruno Reis: Yes, 199 must be the last one and 198 must be just before it. Try to imagine it in another way: All 100 children stand side by side. You only have to decide where to split them into groups and find all solutions for this. Is this more comprehensible?

Comment: Now it is perfect. I suggest you to rephrase exactly like this in your question!

Comment: Thanks for helping me to rephrase it! :) I've added it to the question now as "Short and easy".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand it, you are effectively asking for ways of partitioning the interval [100,199] into 10 parts, i.e. you want to find numbers x[0], ..., x[10] such that:

```
x[0] = 100 < x[1] < x[2] < ... < x[9] < x[10] = 199
```

Define a recursive function `partition(intervalSize, pieces)` which counts the number of ways to partition a given interval. You are after `partition(100, 10)`.

The following Java code counts the partitions (sorry, don't know PHP that well):

```
public class Partitions
{
    static long[][] partitions = new long[100][10];

    private static long partition(int intervalSize, int pieces)
    {
        if (partitions[intervalSize-1][pieces-1] != 0) {
            return partitions[intervalSize-1][pieces-1];
        }
        long partition = 0L;
        if (pieces == 1) {
            partition = 1L;
        } else {
            for (int i = 1; i <= intervalSize - 1; i++) {
                partition += partition(intervalSize - i, pieces - 1);
            }
        }
        partitions[intervalSize-1][pieces-1] = partition;
        return partition;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(partition(100, 10));     
    }

}
```

The following Java code prints out the actual partitions. Because the number of partitions is so high for (100,10), I'm illustrating the answer for (5,3):

```
public class Partitions2
{
    private static void showPartitions(int sizeSet, int numPartitions)
    {
        showPartitions("", 0, sizeSet, numPartitions);
    }

    private static void showPartitions(String prefix, int start, int finish,
            int numLeft)
    {
        if (numLeft == 0 && start == finish) {
            System.out.println(prefix);
        } else {
            prefix += "|";
            for (int i = start + 1; i <= finish; i++) {
                prefix += i + ",";
                showPartitions(prefix, i, finish, numLeft - 1);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        showPartitions(5, 3);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
|1,|2,|3,4,5,
|1,|2,3,|4,5,
|1,|2,3,4,|5,
|1,2,|3,|4,5,
|1,2,|3,4,|5,
|1,2,3,|4,|5,
```

Comment: Thank you! This should be your code in PHP: http://paste.bradleygill.com/index.php?paste_id=15709 Unfortunately, it takes a very long time (>30sec) or runs infinitely. Is there a mistake anywhere in the code? Maybe you can compare your code with the code Juliet linked to?

Comment: It's a recursive function which will get much faster if you memoize (i.e. remember values of the function you've already computed).

Comment: @marco92w: Java code I've just added terminates in under a second

Comment: There must be some differences between your java code and my PHP code. Can someone find them? For (100, 10), my PHP script terminates after 60 seconds. But I got a result for (25, 7): It's 134,596. Is this what you get, too? How could your code (the PHP version) be optimized? Does your java code give back the list instead of the pure count?

Comment: I agree with your result for (25,7). My result for (100,10) is 1731030945644. The reason the Java code to count them is faster than the PHP code is memoization; i.e. cache the result in an array before returning it, so it doesn't have to be recomputed.

Comment: How can your value for 100 be bigger than the normal partition value for 100? Your value is just a special case of the partition (only for 10 parts) so there must be less results, right? Which results should be cached? The sum for a pair of intervalSize and pieces? So I would first check if the value is already in the cache and else do the calculations?

Comment: The normal partition function p(n) counts unordered partitions (e.g. the partition 100 = 20 + 80 is considered the same as 100 = 80 + 20). We are counting ordered partitions. Does that explain the disprepancy?

Comment: The thing you memoize is the value of partition(intervalSize, pieces), otherwise you have to recompute it for every single partition (very slow).

Comment: Thank you so much! Unbelievable how big the effect of caching/memoizing is. Now I get the result for (100,10) in under a second, too: 1.731.030.945.644

Comment: But I still don't understand the discrepancy: We have an additional constraint so our result should be smaller than the normal partition value!?

Comment: No, as I said, the normal partition value is counting UNORDERED partitions. If it was counting ordered partitions, the value would be much higher (and in fact higher than the value we've calculated).

Comment: To make this explicit, the 3 ordered partitions 12|34|5, 12|3|45 and 1|23|45 would be counted as a single unordered partition (5=2+2+1). Because we are counting some unordered partitions many times, our value comes out as bigger than p(100).

Answer (score 0):

> I need all possible solutions for
>   these groups since it isn't hard to
>   find one constellation.

Normally, there 100! ways to permute 100 items, but since you're preserving order, you can reduce your problem size down *substantially*. What you're describing is an [integer partitioning problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)). For example, let's say you were partitioning the number 5 into all possible integer subsets which add up to 5, you'd get the sets {5}, {4, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 1, 1,}, {2, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}.

The number of integer partitions grows exponentially with the size of the integer, but the exponential growth is slow enough that you can enumerate through all partitions of n = 100, since there are only 190,569,292 of them. The additional constraint here is that you want to filter all of your partitions for sets containing exactly 10 items, which is easy to enumerate through using a Ferrer diagram.

I can demonstrate a Ferrer diagram by partition the number 20 into 3 buckets: start with a 20 col x 3 row grid as follows:

```
 12345678901234567890
1******************
2*
3*
```

So, the first partition is {18, 1, 1}

Now move an item from the top of the stack into the next slot:

```
 12345678901234567890
1*****************
2**
3*
```

Our new partition is {17, 2, 1}. We can another item from one stack to the other:

```
 12345678901234567890
1****************
2***
3*
```

Now we have {16, 3, 1}. You continue in this fashion until you've enumerate all permutations (its up to you whether {17, 1, 2} is a distinct partition from {17, 2, 1}).

From this point, you should be able to envision the general outline of the algorithm you need -- that is, if you'd like the challenge of writing this function from scratch. Other people have already [written lots of efficient functions](http://home.att.net/~numericana/answer/numbers.htm#partitions) to solve the problem easily.

Comment: Thank you. The function I need from the linked page should be this, shouldn't it? http://paste.bradleygill.com/index.php?paste_id=15708 Does this give me only the number of partitions or even the list? Can someone help me transfering it to PHP?